# "e.preventDefault()" or "return false" get me to the top

Tags: jquery

jQuery:

```
$("#envoyer_comm").click(function(e){
    comment_value = $("#text_commentaire").val();
    $.get("set_commentaire.php", {idP:idPhoto, commentaire:comment_value});
    param = "idP=" + idPhoto;
    $("#les_commentaires").load("load_commentaire.php", param);
    $("#text_commentaire").val("");
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

set_commentaire.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pure', 'root', 'Starwars');
$insert_com = $bdd->prepare("INSERT INTO commentaire (idUserCom, idPhoto, commentaireValue) VALUES (?,?,?)");
echo $_GET['idP'].$_GET['commentaire'];
$insert_com->execute(array(1,$_GET['idP'], $_GET['commentaire']));
?>
```

load_commentaire.php:

```
<?php
session_start();
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=pure', 'root', 'Starwars');
$req_commentaire = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM commentaire WHERE idPhoto = ? ORDER BY idCom ASC");
$req_commentaire->execute(array($_GET['idP']));
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=1.1">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
        <title>Pure</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
        while($resultat = $req_commentaire->fetch()){
            $req_user = $bdd->prepare("SELECT * FROM utilisateur WHERE idUser = ?");
            $req_user->execute(array($resultat['idUserCom']));
            $userinfo = $req_user->fetch();
            echo "<tr><td><div id=\"commentaire\"><label>".$userinfo['pseudo']."</label><div id=\"commentaire_value\">".$resultat['commentaireValue']."</div></div></td></tr>";
        }   ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

`envoyer_comm` is just a button :

```
<button id="envoyer_comm">Envoyer</button>
```

I don't want my webpage to refresh after this function.

```
e.preventDefault();
```

or

```
return false;
```

do the job but it takes me to the top of my page, i want it to stay where i am

Any ideas ?

Comment: What content is this `$("#les_commentaires").load("load_commentaire.php", param);` loading?  Is that why it is scrolling?  And, what kind of control is `#envoyer_comm`?

Comment: So, you're trying to load a whole HTML document into `#les_commentaires`.  I have no idea what either jQuery or the browser will do when you try that as it's not legal HTML.  I don't know if that is causing your problem, but it's incorrect code.

Comment: $("#les_commentaires").load(file.php, param) means that what's in the body tags in the file.php file goes to the #les_commentaire (div tag), don't try to understand what my script does, it works !